# Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a6328094/public_html/pages/admin/news.php on line 87

Tags: php, mysql, session

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a6328094/public_html/pages/admin/news.php on line 87
Full code, the echos are in hungarian language! so you can look all:

```
      <?PHP
  if($_SESSION['user_admin']>=$adminRights['web_news']) {
?>
<br>
<h2>Hírek áttekintése</h2>
<p>Itt lehet híreket írni és szerkeszteni.</p>

<h3>Hírek Hozzáadása</h3>

<?PHP
  if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Megad&aacute;s")
  {
    if(!empty($_POST['titel']) && !empty($_POST['inhalt']) && checkInt($_POST['kategorie']) && checkBetween($_POST['tag'],0,31) && checkBetween($_POST['monat'],1,12) && checkBetween($_POST['jahr'],1900,date("Y",time())+10) && checkBetween($_POST['stunde'],0,24) && checkBetween($_POST['minute'],0,59))
    {
      $zeitStempel = mktime($_POST['stunde'],$_POST['minute'],0,$_POST['monat'],$_POST['tag'],$_POST['jahr']);
      // id     titel   inhalt  datum   hot     kategorie   author  anzeigen

      $anzeigen = (isset($_POST['anzeigen']) && $_POST['anzeigen']=="true") ? 1 : 0;
      $wichtig = (isset($_POST['wichtig']) && $_POST['wichtig']=="true") ? 1 : 0;


      $sqlNews = "INSERT INTO ".SQL_HP_DB.".news
      VALUES (NULL,'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titel'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inhalt'])."','".$zeitStempel."','".$wichtig."','".$_POST['kategorie']."','".$_SESSION['user_id']."','".$anzeigen."')";

      if(mysql_query($sqlNews,$sqlHp))
      {
        echo'<p class="meldung">Hírek sikeresen létrehozva.</p>';
      }
      else 
      {
        echo'<p class="meldung">A Híreket nem lehetett elmenteni az adatbázisba.</p>';
      }
    }
  }
?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php?s=admin&a=news">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th class="topLine">Cím:</th>
      <td class="thell"><input class="bar" class="bar" type="text" size="40" maxlength="200" name="titel"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="topLine">Tartalom:</th>
      <td class="tdunkel"><textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="inhalt"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="topLine">Dátum:</th>
      <td class="tdunkel"><input class="bar" class="bar" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?PHP echo date("d",time()); ?>" name="tag"/>.<input class="bar" class="bar" type="text" size="2" value="<?PHP echo date("m",time()); ?>" maxlength="2" name="monat"/>.<input class="bar" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="<?PHP echo date("Y",time()); ?>" name="jahr"/> - <input class="bar" class="bar" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?PHP echo date("H",time()); ?>" name="stunde"/>:<input class="bar" class="bar" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?PHP echo date("i",time()); ?>" name="minute"/> Uhr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="topLine">Kategória:</th>
      <td class="thell">
        <?PHP listNewsKat(); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="topLine">Fontos Hírek:</th>
      <td class="tdunkel"><input type="checkbox" name="wichtig" value="true"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="topLine">Kiírás:</th>
      <td class="thell"><input type="checkbox" name="anzeigen" value="true"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="topLine" colspan="2"><input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Megad&aacute;s"/></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<h3>Hír Lista</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="topLine">ID</th>
    <th class="topLine">Dátum</th>
    <th class="topLine">Cím</th>
    <th class="topLine">Kategoria</th>
    <th class="topLine">Fontos</th>
    <th class="topLine">Kiírás</th>
    <th class="topLine">Töröl</th>
  </tr>
  <?PHP
    $sqlNews = "SELECT * FROM ".SQL_HP_DB.".news ORDER BY datum DESC";
    $qryNews = mysqli_query($sqlNews,$sqlHp) or die(mysql_error());
    $x=0;
    while($getNewz = mysqli_fetch_object($qryNews))
    {
      $nWichtig = ($getNews->hot>0) ? "./images/success.gif" : "./images/fail.gif";
      $nAnzeigen = ($getNews->anzeigen>0) ? "./images/success.gif" : "./images/fail.gif";

      $nTitel = (strlen($getNews->titel)>60) ? substr($getNews->titel,0,strpos($getNews->titel,' ',60)).'...' : $getNews->titel;

      $zF = ($x%2==0) ? "tdunkel" : "thell";
      echo'<tr>
        <td class="'.$zF.'">'.$getNews->id.'</td>
        <td class="'.$zF.'">'.getDatum($getNews->datum).'</td>
        <td class="'.$zF.'"><a href="index.php?s=admin&a=news_edit&id='.$getNews->id.'">'.$nTitel.'</a></td>
        <td class="'.$zF.'">'.$newsKategorien[$getNews->kategorie].'</td>
        <td class="'.$zF.'"><img src="'.$nWichtig.'" alt="wichtig"/></td>
        <td class="'.$zF.'"><img src="'.$nAnzeigen.'" alt="wichtig"/></td>
        <td class="'.$zF.'"><a href="index.php?s=admin&a=news_delete&id='.$getNews->id.'"><img src="./images/fail.gif" alt="delete"/></a></td>
      </tr>';
      $x++;
    }
  ?>
</table>
<?PHP
  }
  else {
    echo'<p class="meldung">Nincs hozz&aacute;f&eacute;r&eacute;sed ehhez a területhez!</p>';
  }
      ?>
```

Comment: Well, you do no error checking at all. That is why you don't see the error that is probably cause by your query which is presumably invalid. You should check if `mysql_query()`actually succeeds before you can use its output. Also a look into the error log file would reveal such an issue...

Comment: Which MySQL API are you using to connect with? `mysqli_`? PDO?

Comment: @arkascha `$sqlHp` is most likely their connection parameter variable. Who knows till we know for sure which API they're using to connect with. At this point, it's anybody's "guess".

Comment: `SQL_HP_DB` that's a constant; so your question is very much **unclear**.

Comment: I suggest you dump the query string you construct in the first line. I would expect it is invalid. Have a try executing it manually if it looks fine.

Comment: You're using sessions. Did you start the session? Plus, again.... Which MySQL API are you using to connect with? mysqli_? PDO? You may also be outputting before header without even knowing. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Plus, if that's your full code, I don't see a connection anywhere. You're also mixing MySQL APIs. Those do NOT intermix with each other.

Comment: I got the connection stored in an other file

Comment: Can you "answer" my question please? [Click here... for the one I asked almost 15 mins. ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195584/warning-mysql-fetch-object-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-res#comment46604184_29195584) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195584/warning-mysql-fetch-object-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-res#comment46604368_29195584)

Comment: 000webhost.com, im using this hosting, i dont know what they are using..

Comment: No, your connection to your database. Does it start with `mysqli_connect()` or `mysql_connect()`? or PDO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want to change your while like so:

```
while($getNewz = mysqli_fetch_object($qryNews))
```

Also, I don't understand why would you use deprecated mysql_ calls instead of mysqli_. You should change all those calls. Also your query should read:

```
$qryNews = mysqli_query($sqlNews,$sqlHp) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: No, the OP wants to get an object, not an array. You can tell that by looking at how the content is accessed: `$getNews->anzeigen`

Comment: Plus, OP is using `mysql_`

Comment: @Eda190 Whilst it certainly is a good idea to use the more modern mysqli extension this is not the issue here...

Comment: @arkascha Eda190's second line of code, goes against everything in OP's question. Using `mysqli_query()` then `mysql_error()`. Why I asked the OP which connection API they're using.

Comment: Now got an other Error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/a6328094/public_html/pages/admin/news.php on line 85

Comment: `or die(mysql_error())` that doesn't mix with `mysqli_`. So there, OP is most likely using `mysqli_` to connect with.

Comment: @Kalip Sorry, just ignore this answer until it has been sorted out. It does not make sense in its current state.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I have been using mysql_error() sucesfully on mysqli_query calls. It does return the correct error if found.

Comment: MySQL APIs **do not** intermix. Find me someone who will say differently.

Comment: I just tested it again on my localhost, and it does normally display error. It may be incorrect call, but it does work.
@Kalip How does your database connection look like?

Comment: @Kalip What about files where you dont call an object, but just connect into the database? Seems to me that there is problem with connecting to the database.

Comment: I can connect, i tried it now it works fine, but now, no errors, but if i click on the Submit button it doesnt send it to the database...

Comment: @Kalip Are you still using `mysql_error()`? If the query is not correct, it should generate the error. Otherwise the query would be sent to your database.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a6328094/public_html/pages/admin/news.php on line 99